# Import string RSA public key to use RSA encryption in Go

Tags: go, encryption, rsa

How can I import an RSA public key from a string in Go, so that it can be used to encrypt data ?

My program should do the following:

- Receives a public key encoded in base64
- Decode this public key from base64 to bytes
- Import that public key so that it is usable by the RSA implementation of Go 
  (Problem is at this stage)
- Encrypt an AES key with:

  `ciphertext, err := rsa.EncryptOAEP(sha256.New(), rand.Reader, publicKey, plaintextBytes, []byte(""))`

Thank you in advance !

**SOLUTION**:

The public key has to be decoded with the **crypto/x509** package.

For example:

```
publicKeyInterface, err := x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(publicKeyDER)
if err != nil {
    log.Println("Could not parse DER encoded public key (encryption key)")
    return []byte(""), err
}
publicKey, isRSAPublicKey := publicKeyInterface.(*rsa.PublicKey)
if !isRSAPublicKey {
    log.Println("Public key parsed is not an RSA public key")
    return []byte(""), err
}
```

You can then use the `publicKey` with RSA to encrypt.

Comment: Please refer [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)   Could you include some more code that you've tried so far? To reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of the issue you are having.

Answer (score 0):

When you receive the base64 encoded password your decode like:

```
base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString("FExEiYPgwrHHyO7DOwCXHNRvVF2S8xirXftuFWmJUzo=")
```

Then the string you encrypt must be no longer than the length of the public modulus minus twice the hash length, minus 2. See [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/#EncryptOAEP) for examples and documentation.